# how to join two repositories to one repository GIT

Tags: git, merge, repository

I have created a project and it contains 2 folders.
`API` UI
both two folders contain 2 different repositories (local).
Now I want to push those 2 repositories to one remote repository.
how can I do this

Answer (score 0):

In the remote repo you could setup a `git submodule` for each of your local repos.  Ensure each of your local repos have a remote configured to the relevant submodule of the remote repo.